# Error while displaying crystal reports from VisualStudio2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, postgresql, c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2010

Dear Colleagues,

I have a problem with displaying reports which are generated by VisualStudio2010.
I have prepered all reports  and they works fine but when i try to generate reports from another computer then I receive error: **"string is excepted here"**
I am very dissapointed because some copupters display raports properly but not all and I do not know why :(.
Anyway, i have checked formula which causes this error. It looks like:

```
"if ({parametry_extra.prx_konta_wirtualne}) <> true then {faktura_vat.nkn_nazwa_banku}&" nr "&{faktura_vat.nkn_nr_konta} else {faktura_vat.nkn_nazwa_banku}&" nr "&{faktura_vat.konto1}&" "&{faktura_vat.konto2}"
```

Above formule is correct but why it doesnot work on diffrents computers? I suppose that some computers try to thread boolean value as string("true"/"false"), bool (true/false) or int (1/0)?

Do You know how to resolve this issue?

Many thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.
The problem was in data sources. In "Advanced options" in panel "DataTypeOptions" I disabled  value **"Bools as Char"** and now it works propelry.